# What does version.x mean?

Tags: semantic-versioning

When you browse on the Internet and find paragraphs saying a version number followed by a dot (.) and ex (x), in programs usually. E.g. in *Minecrat 1.8.x*, or *Apache 1.x*.

Comment: It means *anything here*. Just like in algebra.

Comment: Yup. I've answered that myself below.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that this was a self-answered question. Sorry. Then, may I ask, how is this related to programming? If anything, this is software engineering/design and would perhaps be more appropriate on [Programmers.SE].

Comment: Can I move it or do I have to delete and reask there?

Comment: @CodyGray when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

It is called **[Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)**, and it's just a geeky way to display unspecific versioning (i.e. versions of a software/hardware). In semantic versioning (link above) the format is X.Y.Z (MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH).

Just like in math, each letter represents a variable. X is for a major version, Y for minors and Z for patches.

Let's take the Minecraft (a videogame) example: the game has a version of 1.8, and within this version they have patches (very small versions/changes), such as 1.8.8, 1.8.9, etc. If you're writing a paragraph and want to refer to all versions (**patches**) as long as they're from the **major version** 1.8, you can replace the formula X.Y.Z with **1.8.X**.

Of course, you don't have to type it like that, since 1.8 will refer to all. Again, just a geeky way.

Some people don't follow the formula of X.Y.Z and simply enter the variable version/patch as Z, as in the Apache example, where it's 1.X instead of the correct way --acording to Semantic Versioning-- 1.Y.

Comment: But why would you create a version with a letter in it? There's an example of that here: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html#versioning-documentation
It says “Create branch: 1.0.x from ‘main’”. Why isn't it called 1.0.0?